# SharePoint 2010 search crawl log error

Tags: search, sharepoint-server

I want to get us out of the search crawl log error "The Share Point item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item".
As per few article I did the changes in registry, restarted server, reset search index and restarted search service. But still I'm getting the error.

Does anybody have permanent solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

are you using the session state in the Sharepoint, you need to turn on. Sharepoint doesn't turn this on by default.
check here for complete detail:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e99f2c44-e432-48ee-abeb-3fdda33a608f/the-sharepoint-item-being-crawled-returned-an-error-when-attempting-to-download-the-item?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious